# How to get ALT Text from Instagram Graphql API?

Tags: graphql, instagram

I'm trying to get alt text of a picture on instagram, but the following endpoint does not work

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=b3055c01b4b222b8a47dc12b090e4e64&variables={
  media_object(id: "C4SqQlcMX20") {
    caption
    media_type
    media_url
    thumbnail_url
    permalink
    timestamp
    username
    accessibility_caption
  }
}
```

I get this message:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"execution error","severity":"CRITICAL"}],"status":"ok"}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using a very old endpoint there, that is probably not even supported any more. Officially supported IG APIs are described under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/